# Is there any way I can use isMulti without it deleting choices I've already picked? In otherwords, having duplicate/repeated selected options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Basically, I want to use the [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) library and use the isMulti prop, but the problem with that after selecting an option, the value would be deleted. As you can see below with the provided images, as soon as I click "US: 1" that option would go away. But for the app I'm trying to build, it's certainly possible for a customer to want 2 of the same sizes. Therefore they would pick 2 "US: 1" and it automatically sets the quantity to 2. The problem is that as soon as they pick "US: 1" that option goes away.

This is all I currently have now.

```
const options = [
    {value: 1, label: "US: 1"},
    {value: 1.25, label: "US: 1.25"},
    {value: 1.5, label: "US: 1.5"},
    {value: 1.75, label: "US: 1.75"},
    {value: 2, label: "US: 2"},
    {value: 2.25, label: "US: 2.25"},
]
class Details extends Component {
 state={
        selectedOption: []
    }
 handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption: selectedOption });

    }
render() {

<Select isMulti={true} isSearchable={true} onClick={value.changeSize(id, selectedOption)} value={selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange} options={options}></Select>
}
}
```

Here's an example of what I'm talking about. "US: 1" goes away when it's clicked when I want that option to stay. I'm thinking it alters my "options" array and displaying the new one that doesn't have the clicked option. If I can somehow keep feeding it these original values after every single on onChange that would be awesome.  I'm not sure how to dig into the library on how to do it or if it's even possible. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select

[image: https://i.imgur.com/1g7nI2z.png]
[image: https://i.imgur.com/djNjjvL.png]

Comment: Could you provide information on how you want to change the selected count? By selection in the menu or by click on the tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how I would do it:

```
class Details extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: []
  };
  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    const newSelectedOption = selectedOption.map(opt => ({
      label: opt.label,
      innerValue: opt.value,
      // I set a random value because it is needed to be able to delete the value without deleting all of them
      value: Math.random()
    }));
    this.setState({ selectedOption: newSelectedOption });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        isMulti={true}
        isSearchable={true}
        value={this.state.selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The idea is not to use `value` as it's original goal. When a `label` props is passed to `value` inside `Select` it still displays it correctly. So you will base yourself on `innerValue` and trick `react-select`.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/0q27n76j80)

Comment: THANKS FOR THE HELP! this seems to have done the trick! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I guess all you need is to add `hideSelectedOptions={false}` to `<Select />`.
Like:

```
<Select 
  isMulti={true} 
  hideSelectedOptions={false}
  options={options}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a slightly clean version of what @Laura provided.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const ReactMultiSelectDuplicate = ({ options = [], onChange = null }) => {
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectOption] = useState([]);

    const handleChange = changedOptions => {
      const newSelectedOption = changedOptions.map(op => ({ ...op, value: Math.random() * Math.random() }));
      setSelectOption(newSelectedOption);
      if (onChange) {
        onChange(newSelectedOption.map(({ label, av: value}) => ( {label, value } )))
      }
    };
      return (
        <Select
          isMulti
          hideSelectedOptions={false}
          isClearable={true}
          value={selectedOptions}
          onChange={handleChange}
          options={options.map(op => ({...op, av: op.value, value: Math.random() * Math.random() }))}
        />
      );
};

export default ReactMultiSelectDuplicate;
```

Then in your actual component, use this like below:

```
<ReactMultiSelectCustom
  options={options}
  onChange={(values) => console.log(values)}
/>
```

In Laura's answer, the first selection doesn't have the `innerValue` property.